# How to call new operator for the type of an array

Tags: c++, pointers, types, new-operator

`static int (*g_data)[3];`

I'd like to `new` `N` elements of `int[3]`. I'm only able to this as follows:

`g_data = (int(*)[3]) new int[N*3];`

I know that this is okay and using `struct` would be an alternative solution. But, just for curiosity, can I directly call `new` for `int[3]`, i.e., without the type conversion?

Comment: `new` is not just some fancy `malloc`.

Comment: @Joachim I don't think that's a good duplicate.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: You're right. Unfortunately it seems not possible to cancel a close-vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `g_data` is a pointer to a 1D array of 3 `int`, to make an array of N such arrays of 3, you simply use `int [N][3]`:

```
g_data = new int[N][3];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
static int (*g_data)[3];
typedef int int_array[3];
g_data = new int_array[N];
```

Comment: And even better, declare `g_data` with the typedef: `static int_array* g_data;`

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: Yes, thanks!!